# Dynamic Where Clause in LINQ Syntax error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to build a dynamic WHERE clause in my LINQ statement, however I have encountered some problems.

At the moment I have the following:-

```
string[] types = typeId[0].Split(','); //contains string array like {"1,2,3"}
marketing = marketing.Where( type => types.Contains(type.TypeID)).ToList();
```

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: on types.Contains :- "'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<int>(IQueryable<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>' "

Comment: `type.TypeID` is a `string`? If not, you may need to parse it to `int` or change `types` to `int[]`.

Comment: You are telling us that you have an error but this alone does not help us. Can you  explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: What is type of TypeID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, `type.TypeID` is an `int`.

So you basically have 2 options:

Option 1: convert `types` to `int[]`:

```
int[] types = typeId[0].Split(',').Select(id => int.Parse(id)).ToArray();
marketing = marketing.Where( type => types.Contains(type.TypeID)).ToList();
```

Option 2: convert `type.TypeID` to `string`:

```
string[] types = typeId[0].Split(',');
marketing = marketing.Where( type => types.Contains(type.TypeID.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes I went with the .ToString() approach.  Thanks for your help!